# Difference between two sources to install nvm on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nvm

I'm installing a new Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine and also need to install `nvm`.
When searching how to get `nvm` on my system I find two different ways:

`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash`

and

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash`
(or with a different version, whatever is the latest)

I assume they will both do the same, but I want to make sure I'm not installing anything wrong on this system.

Is one of these sources more recommendable than the other?

Comment: It could be a great time to also check out some other options like [`volta`](https://github.com/volta-cli/volta) and [`asdf`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf).

Answer (score 3):

Use the one provided in the official documentation [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script):

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`

I believe both are "safe", as `creationix` appears to be one of the original maintainers. I would however always go for the source from the official repository.